# Nested MVVM and RelayCommand

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

my app uses a nested ViewModel structure. I have a parent view model which contains a list of child view models. The binding works fine and I can execute a relaycommand from a button just fine.

While this works fine, I can only access the data from within the child viewmodel, not from the parent. How can I access data from the parent viewmodel or execute a function on the parent viewmodel and pass the data it needs from the child to the parent?

Edit: This is what my view models look like:

Parent:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }

private RelayCommand _parentCommand;

    public RelayCommand ParentCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parentCommand== null)
            {
                _parentCommand= new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    //some code
                },

                () => true);                   
            }

            return _parentCommand;
        }
    }
```

Child:

```
public string Name_Child { get; set; }

private RelayCommand _childCommand;

    public RelayCommand ChildCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_childCommand== null)
            {
                _childCommand= new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    //some code
                },

                () => true);                   
            }

            return _childCommand;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I need to use both Name_Child and Name from the parent viewmodel and i can only access one of them in the RelayCommands.

Comment: Can you please show us how do you structure your view models? at least briefly..

Comment: I updated my original post with the viewmodels, I hope this helps.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Is it the accepted answer for your question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access data from the parent viewmodel or execute a function on the parent viewmodel and pass the data it needs from the child to the parent?

If your `RelayCommand` need to be executed with parameters, you need to use `RelayCommand<T>` instead of `RelayCommand`. Since you have a List of Child ViewModel, I assume that you can correctly access to child view model. Then for example, you can modify the `RelayCommand` in your parent view model like this:

```
private RelayCommand<string> _parentCommand;
private string parameter;

public RelayCommand<string> ParentCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_parentCommand == null)
        {
            _parentCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(parameter => child.ChildCommand.Execute(parameter));

        }

        return _parentCommand;
    }
}
```

Then in your Child view model for example:

```
public ChildViewModel()
{
    ChildCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((s) => Test(s));
}

public RelayCommand<string> ChildCommand { get; set; }

private void Test(string s)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```